# Sending asynchronous cURL requests to AWS in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, amazon-web-services, curl, libcurl

For a project, I am trying to use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) to scale up my computations. Because the project needs communication/synchronization among worker nodes, I fire up a static master process (usually my laptop) to coordinate among the workers.

However, I have experienced some problems when using cURL's [Easy C-API](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html), especially when I deal with `W > 256` Lambda workers. Basically, I form POST requests and send it to the AWS Gateway API using multiple threads (for this, I use C++11). A representative code excerpt is as follows:

```cpp
/* #include cURL and other libraries */

size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
  auto data = static_cast<string *>(userdata);
  *data = string(ptr, nmemb);
  return nmemb;
}

void spawn_worker(const string &gateway, const string &address,
                  const uint16_t port, const index_t widx) {
  // Below was needed to overcome excessive SSL library errors
  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(widx * 10));
  const string post(/* post data */);
  CURL *handle = nullptr;
  string data;
  ofstream log("worker-" + to_string(widx) + ".log");
  do {
    curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
    handle = curl_easy_init();
    try {
      if (handle != nullptr) {
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, gateway.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);

        log << "Sending the post data: " << post << '\n';
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(handle);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
          throw runtime_error(curl_easy_strerror(res));

        log << "curl_easy_perform() returned:\n" << data << '\n';
        break;
      } else
        throw runtime_error("Cannot initialize cURL.");
    } catch (const exception &e) {
      log << "Exception occured: " << e.what() << '\n';
      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
    };
  } while (true);
  curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  /* variables */
  curl_res = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  if (curl_res != 0)
    return -1;

  /* W: the total number of active Lambda functions needed */
  vector<thread> spawners(W);
  index_t w{0};

  for (auto &spawner : spawners)
    spawner = thread(spawn_worker, gateway, address, port, w++);

  /* algorithm logic */

  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

I have two questions regarding the above code:

1. When I go above 50-100 AWS workers, I observe OpenSSL-related errors in my logs, if I do not make threads sleep for a bit of time. Is this reasonable, or am I doing something wrong? I believe that I am using the multi-thread approach correctly as I am calling `curl_global_init` once, before I fire up my threads, which is mentioned in the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html). Is there a cleaner way of doing what I am trying to do?
2. The lambda workers call a child process (I am using a `worker.js` in AWS which calls a compiled C++ runtime as a child process), and they give the function responsible for returning a JSON object (just some log) as a callback to the child process. In other words, the gateway responds when the workers finish their job, or simply get timed-out (15 minutes). Hence, I see timeout messages in my log coming from my spawners. Seeing timeout messages from cURL is not a big deal, as my algorithm logic in the master process knows what's going on by checking the worker indices attached to the workers' messages. The question is whether I can have a solution where I just send cURL requests to the gateway *without* waiting for a response and *at the same time* making sure that the workers are spawned (no SSL problems whatsoever).

Thank you in advance for your time!